# How to run Wiselib - RDF Provider?

Tags: rdf, sensors

I want to use **Wiselib** to convert **sensor data into RDF** and then store them in Wiselib store. Its source code is available in https://github.com/ibr-alg/wiselib/.

I followed the steps in Github Wiki page to compile and run it in Ubuntu. I compiled an existing example application, *wiselib/apps/generic_apps/rdfprovider_test/* and an executable file got created. But the problem is that I face an error (Segmentation fault) when I run that executable file.

```
$ ./rdfprovider_test
--- init codec_ts
--- init broker
--- inserting documents
create doc1
init free: -1
create doc1
init free: -1
create doc1
init free: -1
ins
init free: -1
ins
init free: -1
ins
init free: -1
ins
ins
ins
ins
ins
ins
ins
ins
ins done
--- testing broker
masks=1 2 4

--- iter doc1:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I do not have much idea on this output.
And also their website (http://wiselib.org/) given in the paper is not available. Is Wiselib not active or am I doing something wrong? Can someone give me instructions to run it?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with the project, but that github repository has not received any updates since 2014, so it looks as if this project has been abandoned. You might try and create an issue in their [issue tracker](https://github.com/ibr-alg/wiselib/issues), or if all else fails try and reach one of its main contributors (they're listed on github) directly. But I wouldn't hold out hope - I note that the two most recent issue tickets were also questions about usage, and they haven't received any response.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I added an issue.
I already emailed them few weeks back using the email addresses given in the research paper, it seems like they are not working. I will reach the main contributors listed in Github, if I didn't get a response from the issue.